# How to create propertyPage having crossbar plus video-decoder in directshow

Tags: visual-studio, video, tabs, device, directshow

I'm new to directshow to show capturing device video. I need to have video decoder (NTSC/PAL) and CrossBar tabs on a single propertPage dialog (see image).
I'm able to show propertyPage separately but I want both in one dialog, as in the image.

In my attempts I was able to get tabs on a page but not getting any inputPin and outputPins in the crossbar tab. I could not get them all to work together. If I manage to get crossbar to work, then the rest of the tabs crash on click???

Please guide me on how to have multiple propertyPages tabs on the same dialog. I'm working in vs2010. Code sample in C++ or .net will be appreciated. Thanks a lot !!!

[image]

Comment: Graphstudionext is able to add "their tabs as its tabs" somehow for its properties dialog, might be worth checking out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a screenshot of standard property page, such as popped up with `OleCreatePropertyFrame` API for specific filter. It is using standard APIs to read and write settings for given COM object (DirectShow filter).

To put the settings onto one page, you can create your own property page, or other UI which talks programmatically to the filter and calls the respective methods via [`IAMCrossbar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`IAMTVTuner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375971%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interfaces.

You won't be able to replace existing property pages for existing (not yours) filter, for use with `OleCreatePropertyFrame` API, but other conbinations are doable:

- custom property page for your filter, with/without `OleCreatePropertyFrame` API
- custom property page for existing filter, without `OleCreatePropertyFrame` API
- custom UI for existing filter

UPD. Another thing is that some standard pages might be filter specific, and other might be pin specific. Standard API shows pages for one object only, that is either filter or pin. In order to combine pages within one sheet, with standard API, you need to enumerate property pages on all objects, merge into single array, then create a fake COM object which forwards `IUnknown::QueryInterface` calls to specific COM objects (or just iterate through through array until you find first one implementing requested interface) and then use `OleCreatePropertyFrame` API against this proxy COM object. This can gather pages under one sheet/dialog.

Comment: thanks. i dont need a custom property page. i just want to have multiple pages (e.g. IAMCrossbar and IAMTVTuner) in one dialog but under their own tab. the screenshot was taken from an application and since you said it is STANDARD page, it should be doable without having to write a custom one. i'm aware of oleCreatePropertyFrame but cant get multiple tabe on one page.  I just need it exactly as in the screenshot.  please guide.

Comment: thanks for advice. as mentioned in my question, i am able to combine crossbar tab with other standard property pages on a property sheet. BUT the crossbar shows empty input and output pins??? any ideads!!!

Comment: this is already done in many video capturing applications but there is no example or explanation found anywhere!!! it seems that i've to manage with a separate crossbar property page. is directshow that complicated??